# Oracle XE 11gR2 where my tables are located?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have created some tables under a system as sysdba session using

```
create table mytable
(
    ID char(20) not null,
    val1 char(150),
    val2 numeric(4)
);
```

when i m trying to query the tables everything works fine but when i m trying to look the contents of all_tables or user_tables with : `eg. SELECT table_name from all_tables` my tables are nowhere to be found...

Why is that? am i missing something?

What i actualy want to do is to calculate the used blocks from a table i created
and the query i use is :

```
SELECT blocks - empty_blocks
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

which because of the problem i explained above does not work.

Comment: what's the schema did you create your tables ?

Comment: What do you mean? i m new to this and i don t understand it very well. What i did is to login to XE database with system as sysdba and created few tables with the code i provided.

Comment: did you use sqlplus to create the table or sqldeveloper  ?

Comment: Table names are stored in upper case, try `table_name = 'MYTABLE'`

Comment: ***Never***, ever create your normal tables using the `SYS` (or `SYSTEM`) account. Create a regular user and use _that_ for your regular work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name exactlly see my anwer

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,

Open `cmd` and write `sqlplus` then connect to user system like this `system as sysdba`,

Secondly,

create a new user `TEST` with password `TEST` with this command `create user TEST identified by TEST;` then grant all privileges to the user like this `grant all privileges to TEST;`

Finally,

connect to the new user with this command `conn TEST/TEST` and create your table

Comment: ok so to understand this the problem was that i created the database with system user? if i create a new user with all privileges the data that i want will be accessible? The reason i ask is that my database's data is around 1.5GB and i want to avoid inserting them again

Comment: no just your adding a new user in the same database

Comment: Before "create user" I had to run: alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;